# How display a table according a value selected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help, i'm programming a `<select>` with 4 values `<option>` i want that the tables no visibles then when i click on the option, show a table, how i can do this?

```html
<select name="ejercicio">
  <option value="16">exercise 2016</option>//when click here display a table
  <option value="17">exercise 2017</option>//when click here display other table
  <option value="18">exercise 2018</option>//***
  <option value="19">exercise 2019</option>//***
</select>
```

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to achieve this. Simpliest way is use jQuery or similar JS libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure weather you referred JQuery in your project.
If you didn't,you can try it like this :
HTML:
[HTML CONTENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vceXk.jpg)
CSS:

```
.table-list{
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
var select = document.getElementById("toggle");
toggle.addEventListener('change',function(){
    var tbs = document.getElementsByClassName('table-list');
for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
    tbs[i].style.display = 'none';
}
var tbName = select.value;
document.getElementById('tbName').style.display = 'block';
});
```

And you can test it [here is the live demo for you](http://jsbin.com/kiwayecife/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to get the index of the selected option and use it in your own function to change the visibility of the table to *true*.

E.g. :
you have four tables, which you name the same except at the end. There you add the later index of the option, which will be used to set the table to visible. In your function, you can use the namespace of the table and append the index of the selected option to get the table and set the visibility of the table.

I hope it'll help :)

Answer (score 0):

its quite simple just verify Value of select and use it to show table here is example

CSS:

```
.tablecontainer li { display: none; }
.tablecontainer li.show { display: block; }
```

HTML:

```
<select name="selectbox">
  <option value="" checked>Select</option> 
  <option value="firsttable">Table 1</option> 
  <option value="sectable">Table 2</option>  
</select>

<ul class="tablecontainer">
 <li id="firsttable">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>First table</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </li>
<li id="firsttable">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>First table</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Finally Jquery:

```
$('select').on("change", function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 $(".tablecontainer")
  .find("#" + $(this).val())
  .addClass("show")
  .siblings()
  .removeClass("show");
});
```

i am sure it will help you.